# UnknownValueError result from recognize_google

Tags: python-2.7, speech-recognition

I cannot understand why I am getting this error when doing speech recognition, it works for a while, but then this error pops up.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/new4.py", line 46, in <module>
    mainfunction(source)
  File "C:/Python27/new4.py", line 27, in mainfunction
    user = r.recognize_google(audio)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 780, in recognize_google
    if not isinstance(actual_result, dict) or len(actual_result.get("alternative", [])) == 0: raise UnknownValueError()
UnknownValueError
```

And this is the code that I am running:

```
def mainfunction(source):
    audio = r.listen(source)
    user = r.recognize_google(audio)

    # recognize speech using Google Speech Recognition
    try:
        # for testing purposes, we're just using the default API key
        # to use another API key, use `r.recognize_google(audio, key="GOOGLE_SPEECH_RECOGNITION_API_KEY")`
        # instead of `r.recognize_google(audio)`
        print("Google Speech Recognition thinks you said " + user)
    except sr.UnknownValueError:
        print("Google Speech Recognition could not understand audio")
    except sr.RequestError as e:
        print("Could not request results from Google Speech Recognition service; {0}".format(e))



if __name__ == "__main__":
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        while 1:
            mainfunction(source)
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: you got any solution for this. I am getting the same error for `r.recognize_google(audio)`.

Answer (score -1):

moved the line "user = r.recognize_google(audio)" into the try block